# Get the screen height with Compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'd like to know how to get the screen height using Compass and Sass (not javascript)?

I don't want to use the percentages like "100%"...

Anthony

Comment: Why do you need the screen height? To apply certain styles? Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use media queries for this.

Comment: To create a OnePage website. Each section of the OnePage website needs to be of the screen height. And if I put "100%", it doesn"t work because I have a "padding-top"...

Comment: You have a couple options here, but let's start by fixing the padding throwing off your percentage height. Have you tried applying the `box-sizing: border-box` model to all elements?

Comment: Now the padding top works with the bow sizing... Thank you. Is that the best way to create a OnePage website, using height equal to 100% ?

Comment: It's one way to do it! Using `position: fixed` is another. It's a lot like `position: absolute`, except that it's always expressed in terms of the browser viewport rather than its closest positioned ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the default (content-box) box-sizing model, any top/bottom padding you add to an element with `height: 100%` will increase the total height past the viewport (not good!). You can solve this using the border-box model, which causes padding to "push content inward."

Under the border-box model, in an element with the dimensions 600px x 600px, adding `padding: 50px` will constrain the content to 550px x 550px. The following snippet of CSS will apply this model to all elements on the page:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you're trying to make a single-page app, you may also find fixed positioning useful. Here's some CSS for an example element which almost fills the browser viewport, but leaves a little room to spare:

```
#an-excellent-app {
   position: fixed;
   top: 20px;
   bottom: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   right: 20px;
}
```

You can use percentages in place of px if you're feeling responsive. Good luck!